# removeListener doesn't work even while using named functions

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, removeeventlistener

This is my code

```js
    const keyUpEvent = (e, someString) => {
        if(e.keyCode === 13){
            console.log(someString);
        }
    }

    const openTaskPopUp = (e) => {
        const someString = "abc";
        const someFunction = (event) => {
            keyUpEvent(event,someString);
        }
        someButton.removeEventListener('keyup' , someFunction);
        someButton.addEventListener('keyup' , someFunction);        
        //code
    }
```

Are both `someFunction` different? Because the `removeEventListener` doesn't work at all. `console.log(someString);` first prints `someString` once, then twice, then thrice and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The issue isn't whether the function is *named* or not, the issue is whether the function you're removing actually exists as a handler on the element for that event. You're still creating the function every time, so the `someFunction` created by one call to `openTaskPopUp` isn't the same function as the `someFunction` created by the next call — so it's not removed.

You need to remember the function you assigned in order to remove it. For instance:

```
const keyUpEvent = (e, someString) => {
    if(e.keyCode === 13){
        console.log(someString);
    }
};

let openTaskPopUpKeyupHandler = null;                                    // ***
const openTaskPopUp = (e) => {
    const someString = "abc";
    someButton.removeEventListener('keyup' , openTaskPopUpKeyupHandler); // ***
    openTaskPopUpKeyupHandler = (event) => {                             // ***
        keyUpEvent(event,someString);
    }
    someButton.addEventListener('keyup' , openTaskPopUpKeyupHandler);    // ***    
    //code
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! You put ``openTaskPopUpKeyupHandler`` after ``removeEventListener`` so that when ``someButton`` calls ``openTaskPopUpKeyupHandler`` for the first time it gets null and doesn't remove anything, did I understand that right?

Comment: @JaswantRathod - Right -- and so that the next time it's called, it removes the previous handler, creates a new one, and then assigns that. (Another approach would be to attach the handler just once using a variable declared in the containing scope, and just change the value of that variable.)